# Converting MS Access IIF to SQL Server CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm trying to convert a MS Access application to SQL Server. I'm getting an error

> incorrect syntax near 'as'

when trying to convert this:

RegSales:

```
Sum(LOTOSMIS_ACC_TYPE.sing_ind*LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY.grs_amn*IIf(gm_cd In (1105,2123,2124,2150,2152,2191,2192,5143,5145,5146,5245,5253),Switch(LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY.gm_var=1,0,True,1),0))
```

To this

```
(SELECT CASE WHEN P.GM_VAR = 1 THEN 0 END)) AS RegSales,
```

I am getting error RegSales:

```
Sum(LOTOSMIS_ACC_TYPE.sing_ind*LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY.grs_amn*IIf(gm_cd In (1105,2123,2124,2150,2152,2191,2192,5143,5145,5146,5245,5253),Switch(LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY.gm_var=1,0,True,1),0))
```

Getting syntax errors

> Incorrect syntax near the word 'as'

or

> Incorrect syntax near  ')'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

If I follow correctly, the logic is:

```
sum(case when gm_cd not in (1105, 2123, 2124, 2150, 2152, 2191, 2192, 5143, 5145, 5146, 5245, 5253)
         then LOTOSMIS_ACC_TYPE.sing_ind * LOTOSMIS_RET_DAILY.grs_amn
         else 0
    end)
```

Comment: 0


Thanks!
SUM(CASE WHEN P.gm_cd in(1105, 2123, 2124, 2150, 2152, 2191, 2192, 5143, 5145, 5146, 5245, 5253 )THEN T.SING_IND * P.GRS_AMN else 0)) as RegSales, Why am I still getting the syntax error "Syntax error near keyword 'AS'?

Comment: OOPs! Forgot END